# Lua Allows to Delete Files in CS2D game

Tags: linux, lua

Linux permissions can't stop Lua from going outside its own directory and into another.

Also, if declaring these values before:

```
os.execute = nil
io.popen = nil
```

It actually solves the problem, but disables many functions, like my clients not being able to use their other saved scripts.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use Linux permissions for this? What if you make your script run as a different user, with reduced permissions? (I know apache does something along this line to prevent script from going outside the "www" folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new linux user, with permissions only for the needed directory, and run as that.

Otherwise there really is no solution. You can sandbox as much as you want, but if those functions are needed then you're out of luck.

Comment: yes, but you can jump between directories with LUA afaik, even if the Linux doesn't allow to change dir

Answer (score 0):

You could always create your wrapper functions around the original os.execute before setting it to nil, so that you have more control of the actions taken. for example:

```
local osExecute = os.execute
os.execute = nil

os.createDir = function(dir)
    osExecute("mkdir "..dir)
end

os.saveScript(script)
    osExecute("command to save script goes here")
end
```

Of course, this example is prone to attacks, you would need to validate the parameters, to make sure it really is a folder name, and not `folder;rm -rf /`, for example.

Same goes for popen, you can always create your set of commands to execute.

You can then, of course create a user with restricted permissions, for extra security.